# query() function PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Sorry guys, I'm new to this, can you help me with my doubt?

What's wrong with my `query()` function? Is it something wrong with the PDO?

**banco.php**

```
<?php  
    class Banco {
        private $pdo;

        public function __construct($host,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpass){
            try {
                $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dbname.";host=".$host."",$dbuser,$dbpass);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Conexao falhou".$e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function query($sql) {
            $this->pdo->query($sql);
        }
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php  
    require 'banco.php';
    $banco = new Banco("127.0.0.1","test","root","");

    $projeto = $banco->query("SELECT * FROM projetos") ;

    $dado = $projeto->fetch();

    print_r($dado);

?>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the logs?

Comment: You should always check if the connection is OK prior to use.  This is one problem with making a connection in a constructor - you can't check immediately if it's worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code like this: (you forgot "return")

```
public function query($sql) {
  return $this->pdo->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Fatal Error - Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

Some quick enhancements:

```
class Banco {
private $pdo;
public function __construct($host,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpass){
    try {
      $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dbname.";host=".$host."",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "Conexao falhou".$e->getMessage();
      }
}
public function query($sql) {
  return $this->pdo->query($sql);
}
}

$banco = new Banco("127.0.0.1","test","root","");

$projeto = $banco->query("SELECT * FROM projetos") ;
$dado = $projeto->fetch();
print_r($dado);

?>
```

---

If PDO statement returns FALSE, it means that query failed. I.e. if this line `$banco->query("SELECT * FROM projetos");` is not a correct query (there can be many reasons) it will give you

> Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

If you want us to really help you on this, you should upload the database structure.